# Change row background color on select field change

Tags: theming, forms

I have a form with a table that has select boxes inside. I need to have each row of the table with a different background depending on the value of the "action" select box. If it's Create it should be green, if it's Delete should be red.

These colors should be applied when I go to the page and also when I change the select box value.

Below is a screenshoot of the table and the complete module code.

Thanks.

[image: Screenshoot]

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['mymodule_menu'] = array(
    'title' => 'My module title',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_form($form, $form_state) {

    $actions = array(
        'create' => 'create',
        'delete' => 'delete',
    );

    $configurations = array(
        'default' => 'default',
        'conf1' => 'conf1',
        'conf2' => 'conf2',
    );

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $options['row' . $i] = array(
            'row' => 'row' . $i,
            'action' => array(
                'data'=> array(
                    '#type' => 'select',
                    '#title' => 'Action for row' . $i,
                    '#title_display'=> 'invisible',
                    '#default_value'=> '',
                    '#options' => $actions,
                    '#name' => 'action[row' . $i . ']',
                ),
            ),
            'configuration' => array(
                'data'=> array(
                    '#type' => 'select',
                    '#title' => 'Configuration for row' . $i,
                    '#title_display'=> 'invisible',
                    '#default_value'=> '',
                    '#options' => $configurations,
                    '#name' => 'configuration[row' . $i . ']',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    $header = array(
        'row' => t('Row'),
        'action' => t('Action'),
        'configuration' => t('Configuration'),
    );

    $form['myfieldset'] = array(
        '#title' => t("This is a fieldset"),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="checkboxes-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#description' => t('This is the fieldset description.'),
    );

    $form['myfieldset']['tableselect_element'] = array(
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $options,
        '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
    );

    $form['action'] = array(
        '#type' => 'value',
    );

    $form['configuration'] = array(
        '#type' => 'value',
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Execute',
    );

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I would handle all logic in some custom js so it can run on the change event.

First add a custom class to your table:

```
$form['myfieldset']['tableselect_element'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
    '#attributes' => ['class' => ['mytable']],
);
```

And a custom class to your action select:

```
'action' => array(
    'data'=> array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Action for row' . $i,
        '#title_display'=> 'invisible',
        '#default_value'=> '',
        '#options' => $actions,
        '#name' => 'action[row' . $i . ']',
        '#attributes' => ['class' => ['update-action']],
    ),
),
```

And then also add some custom javascript to the form:

```
$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.js';
```

Then create the file mymodule.js. Here is an example. I've added comments to explain each bit.

```
(function($) {

    /**
     * The Drupal behaviors to copy address from shipping to billing on admin order edit page.
     */
    Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleColorRows = {
        attach: function(context) {

            // Bind change event to select
            $('.update-action').change(function(){
                setColors();
            });

            // Call function on first page load
            setColors();

            function setColors() {
                // Loop rows
                $('.mytable tr').each(function(){
                    // Get color from value of select
                    var color = $(this).find('.update-action').val() == 'create' ? 'green' : 'red';
                    // Set color
                    $(this).find('td').css({'background-color': color});

                });
            }

        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Then your table should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. If you don't mind if I ask, I can use the same kind of code to disable the select boxes depending on some conditions, right? And also, it's possible to keep track of how many rows I have selected and when I reach 3, it's not possible to choose more?

Comment: Yes, this is all possible and just requires a bit of JavaScript. Check on stackoverflow for resources or ask a question there if you get stuck as none of that is really to do with Drupal...